# FireFTP for Waterfox

Tags: waterfox, fireftp

I'm trying to install the FireFTP addon for Waterfox, but I keep getting the "add on could not be installed because it appears to be corrupted" message. I've downloaded the latest version "version 2.0.32" but it does not seem to want to work. Any ideas anyone? I've tried both the xpi file and the zip file from- https://github.com/mimecuvalo/fireftp/releases/tag/v2.0.32

Answer (score 0):

Tny,
I'm the developer of FireFTP/FireSSH. The add-on is no longer supported unfortunately. I recommend reaching out the Waterfox community to get further support!

Answer (score -1):

It's a real bummer that the developer for FireFTP no longer has a browser that supports it.  Looks like I no longer have a reason to use Waterfox as I already have plenty of other browsers and Waterfox no longer offers the reason I got it.  I specifically added that browser when Firefox stopped supporting FireFTP after using it on Firefox for years.  So now there is no reason to keep this clone of Firefox on my computer.  I'll look for an SFTP client elsewhere.

Looks like FileZilla has a free client available.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1110356)